# F# unit testing: nunit.framework assembly not referenced error

Tags: f#, assembly-binding-redirect, fsunit

I'm playing with unit testing in F#. I'm running Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition. I created a test project and installed `NUnit 2.6.4` and `FsUnit 1.3.0.1`. I used Package Manager Console. I added references to the libraries in the project and in my script file I referenced the DLLs and added `open` clauses:

```
#r @"C:\Users\pw\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\FSharpForQuantFirst\packages\FsUnit.1.3.0.1\Lib\Net40\FsUnit.NUnit.dll"
#r @"C:\Users\pw\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\FSharpForQuantFirst\packages\NUnit.2.6.4\lib\nunit.framework.dll" 

open NUnit.Framework
open NUnit.Framework.Constraints
open FsUnit

1 |> should equal 1
```

There are no errors nor warnings in my code. However, when I run the code in F# Interactive the last line triggers the following error:

> `Test.fsx(8,6)`: error `FS0074`: The type referenced through `'NUnit.Framework.Constraints.Constraint'` is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly `'nunit.framework'`.

But I've already added the reference to `nunit.framework`.

I cleaned the project, reinstalled the packages, removed and added references, but the result is the same. I still get the error. Any idea what's the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

If you may have noticed, there is a `app.config` with binding redirects for `nunit.framework`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.framework" publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.4.14350" newVersion="2.6.4.14350" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

F# Interactive doesn't take this one into account and therefore you have to use `NUnit 2.6.3` which is referenced by `FsUnit.NUnit.dll`.

Please downgrade `NUnit` to `2.6.3` and be sure to reset the F# Interactive session.

Comment: I've uninstalled the `NUnit 2.6.4` and installed version `2.6.3`. But I still get the same error...